# Can't import chainlink contracts

Tags: javascript, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat, chainlink

I've looked though all the other questions on this topic and no answers seem to work, I have run npm i @chainlink/contracts.
But still I can not import these contracts. It works perfectly on remix but in vscode with hardhat, nothing seems to fix it.

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
```

Comment: Are you using `brownie`? If so, make sure you have set up your remappings in `brownie-config.yaml`. Also make sure you're using solidity compiler version 0.8^ since that's the contract version you're importing.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I'm using hardhat not brownie, also I have just checked to make sure the compiler is 0.8^ and it is. Still get this error "Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol" not found: File import callback not supported"

Comment: Are you following some tutorial or example?  Could you add more information?

Comment: No, I am running my own contract that uses the chainlink Verifiable random function, the problem is that this contract works perfectly in remix with the imports. But when I try to run it on vscode with hardhat, and on the kovan testnet, the import will not work at all. Even though I have uninstalled and installed @chainlink/contracts through npm multiple times.

Comment: I've fixed my issue, I switched a different solidity extension on vscode. Also installed @chainlink/contracts with yarn instead of npm. I'm not sure why that fixed it but it did. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, red lines under the imports.

The solution was to change the VSCode Extension - Solidity by Juan Blanco - to Solidity by Nomic Foundation

Solidity by Nomic Foundation
[image]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NomicFoundation.hardhat-solidity

Before

[image]

After
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Github repos for Chainlink/contracts, the path has changed slightly. It's now -
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something in your import path.

you have:

`import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";`

it should be:

`import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";`

this should fix the problem.

** note: make sure you install the chainlink packages via:

`npm install @chainlink/contracts --save`